# How can I group by the difference between rows in a column with linq and c#?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to create a new group when the difference between the values in rows are greater then five.

Example:

```
int[] list = {5,10,15,40,45,50,70,75};
```

should give me 3 groups:

```
1,[ 5,10,15 ]
2,[40,45,50]
3,[70,75]
```

Is it possible to use Linq here?

Thx!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to use LINQ here?  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I have tried to solve this with a loop (not finished yet...). But while I was writing the loop, it doesn't look like a elegant solution to me :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exploiting *side effects* (`group`) is not a good practice, but can be helpful:

```
  int[] list = { 5, 10, 15, 40, 45, 50, 70, 75 };

  int step = 5;
  int group = 1;

  var result = list
    .Select((item, index) => new {
               prior = index == 0 ? item : list[index - 1],
               item = item,
             })
    .GroupBy(pair => Math.Abs(pair.prior - pair.item) <= step ? group : ++group, 
             pair => pair.item);
```

Test:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0}: [{1}]", chunk.Key, String.Join(", ", chunk))));
```

Outcome:

```
1: [5, 10, 15]
2: [40, 45, 50]
3: [70, 75]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming collection has an indexer defined, can be something like this:

```
const int step = 5;
int currentGroup = 1;
var groups = list.Select((item, index) =>
{
    if (index > 0 && item - step > list[index - 1])
    {
        currentGroup++;
    }
    return new {Group = currentGroup, Item = item};
}).GroupBy(i => i.Group).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, just write a function to do it.  This is easier to understand and more readable than the Linq examples given in other answers.

```
public static List<List<int>> Group(this IEnumerable<int> sequence, int groupDiff) {
    var groups = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> currGroup = null;
    int? lastItem = null;
    foreach (var item in sequence) {
        if (lastItem == null || item - lastItem.Value > groupDiff) {
            currGroup = new List<int>{ item };
            groups.Add(currGroup);
        } else {
            // add item to current group
            currGroup.Add(item);
        }
        lastItem = item;
    }
    return groups;
}
```

And call it like this

```
List<List<int>> groups = Group(list, 5);
```

Assumption: `list` is sorted.  If it is not sorted, just sort it first and use the above code.

Also: if you need `groups` to be an `int[][]` just use the Linq Method `ToArray()` to your liking.

Comment: I think that the readability depends on the programmer. The more I work with lambda-functions, the easier it is to read for me.